# Data Science calculate the Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, distance, knn

I need help with this challenge, I tried to do this with different methods but the last few test cases give me error. It's an Sololearn challenge. They gave me permission to get help.

Task:

> Assume that there are two clusters among the given
> two-dimensional data points and two random points (0, 0), and (2, 2)
> are the initial cluster centroids. Calculate the euclidean distance
> between each data point and each of the centroid, assign each data
> point to its nearest centroid, then calculate the new centroid. If
> there's a tie, assign the data point to the cluster with centroid (0,
> 0). If none of the data points were assigned to the given centroid, return None.

Input Format:

> First line: an integer to indicate the
> number of data points (n) Next n lines: two numeric values per each
> line to represent a data point in two dimensional space.

Output Format

> Two lists for two centroids. Numbers are rounded to the second decimal
> place.

Sample Input:

3

1 0

0 .5

4 0

Sample Output:

[0.5  0.25]

[4. 0.]

- My try:

```
n = int(input())
X = []
for i in range(n):
    X.append([float(x) for x in input().split()])
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
scale = StandardScaler()
scale.fit(X)
X_scaled = scale.transform(X)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)
s=(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
for a in s:
    print(np.around(a,2))
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to the relevant part where you need help. Which part of your code does not produce the result you want, and which result did you get instead?

Comment: That's the part I'm not understanding as well, because the last few test cases I'm always getting incorrect answer are locked and I can't look at them. But if I had to guess I guess I needed help with indicating whether data point is assigned or was it a tie.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula based on the Pythagorean Theorem:

Ex.

```
import math

x1 = 1 

y1 = 3

x2 = 6

y2 = 8

a = x2 - x1 #get length "a" of triangle rectangle

b = y2 - y1 #get length "b" of triangle rectangle

c = math.sqrt((a**2) + (b**2)) #distance between two 2D coordinates/hypotenuse
```

Easy to understand, and it's quick and simple.